# Vim - Closing quickfix window yields "E445: Other Window Contains Changes"

Tags: vim

I just switched from tabs to buffers (a bit late) and now got some problems with my quickfix setup. The relevant part of my .vimrc reads:

```
autocmd QuickFixCmdPost [^l]* nested cwindow
autocmd QuickFixCmdPost    l* nested lwindow
map <F8> :on!<CR>
map <F9> :w<CR>:on!<CR>:make<CR>
```

Now when I hit F9 the error window (if there are any windows) pops up as expected.
However hitting F8 or F9 after that (or simply do :on!) gets me an "E445: Other Window Contains Changes" error (the quickfix windows does get closed, but it prevents the make command from getting executed - besides that ugly red error bar).

It doesn't matter if I `:set hidden` or not and yes: I don't edit inside the quickfix window...

Though I don't expect the entire .vimrc to be useful I pasted it here:
http://pastebin.com/ubU0GzTn

Any ideas?

Comment: With `:set hidden`, E445 shouldn't appear any more.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you use a more specific command, `:cclose`, to close the quickfix window, instead of `:only`.

Comment: Well, that did just as promised. Thank you.